lunch and m command failed for undefined symbol in AOSP
I am trying to running lunch and m command in AOSP. In detail, the commands are . ./build/envsetup.sh , lunch aosp_cf_x86_64_phone-trunk_staging-userdebug and m smp-fuzzer. However, the lunch command fails for the following reason:
prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/ckati: symbol lookup error: prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/ckati: undefined symbol: _ZNSt3__15mutexD1Ev

May I know why this happen? Thank you.
Some more notes and what I have done:
(1) The LLVM and clang version is 13.0.1. The lunch command works in Feburary. And the only thing I changed is LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I don't think I can change libc++ code/libc++.so, and ckati is from AOSP itself.
(2) I used c++filt on this symbol, it's std::__1::mutex::~mutex(), which is destructor of libc++ std::mutex. I wrote a very simple program with std::mutex and it can be compiled with clang and execute.
(3) printenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH result: :/scratch/wjw5351/downloads/klee/build/lib:/scratch/wjw5351/opt/libcxx/libc++-build-130/lib:/scratch/wjw5351/downloads/klee/build/lib:/scratch/wjw5351/opt/libcxx/libc++-build-130/lib. There's a duplicate libc++ path while I don't think that matters.
I also tried to export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/scratch/wjw5351/opt/libcxx/libc++-build-130/lib but still doesn't work.
(4) I used ldd prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/ckati and the output seems OK:
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffddebdb000)
libjemalloc5.so => /scratch/wjw5351/aosp_clean/prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/../lib64/libjemalloc5.so (0x00007f978bb51000)
libc++.so => /scratch/wjw5351/opt/libcxx/libc++-build-130/lib/libc++.so (0x00007f978ba4c000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f978ba3a000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f978ba33000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f978b94c000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f978b947000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f978b927000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f978b6fe000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f978be2b000)
libatomic.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatomic.so.1 (0x00007f978b6f4000)


You need to share details like the branch, tag you are using to repo sync. Your machine SW details like the distro version etc...

Thanks for the comment. It's ubuntu 22.04, x86_64. I've also solved this problem.

Finally this got solved by removing /libcxx/libc++-build-130/lib from LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
